# private protected does not work

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a method:

```
private protected string SendRequest(BaseRequest request, string httpMethod, bool isPublicRequest) { ... }
```

BaseRequest is internal, that's why I want to use the new private protected combination.

Unfortunately I still get an error:

> "Modifier 'protected' cannot be combined with 'private'"

I upgraded VS to 15.5.2 so why does it not know the new C# Features?
Clean solution didn't help by the way.

Comment: You need to change the C# version in your solution properties.

Comment: You have to ensure to use the latest C# version in your project build options. Default is C# 7.0 (which is not the latest)

Comment: See https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/865579/How-to-change-targeted-Csharp-version-in-Visual-St - this option can be set for each configuration, so you may want to select all configurations before you change it ;o)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature requires version 7.2.

to accomplish this:

1. Right-click on your project
2. at the bottom of the available options click `Properties`
3. Click on `Build`
4. Click on Advanced
5. Within the pop-up, change the language version to match the required version (7.2)

Also, as @Sir Rufo has mentioned in the comments section you can set this option for each configuration. Therefore changing it for all configurations would be the better option.

more info [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/865579/How-to-change-targeted-Csharp-version-in-Visual-St).

Comment: You should mention that this option can be set for each configuration. Just for Debug you will get an error on Release. Changing it for all configurations is the best option

Comment: It works now thanks. I still get the error displayed because resharper doesn't know that feature but atleast I can build.

Comment: It is worth noting that you can set it to `Latest` as well.